# Spring Security tags not recognized with Thymeleafs

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot with Thymeleafes and Spring security. However Spring security tags are not recognised in view files. They are skipped and both content in authenticated and anynomous blocks is displayed. I tried with both plain spring security tags and thymeleafs tags:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
  authenticated
</div>
<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
  anonymous
</div>
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    authenticated
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
    anonymous
</sec:authorize>
```

The output is :

```
authenticated 
anonymous 
authenticated 
anonymous
```

What can be the problem? Do I need any configuration? Here is my pom file content. Thanks in advance for help

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>   
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Did you read all the other questions on SO about that subject?

Comment: Yes and I did everything that there was mentioned.